# Difference between Spring Data Neo4j 3.4.0.RELEASE and 4.0.0.RELEASE

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Currently, there are two SDN releases:

```
Spring Data Neo4j 3.4.0.RELEASE 
Spring Data Neo4j 4.0.0.RELEASE
```

[Spring Data Neo4J](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/)

What is the point to have them both?

Which one should I use in my application ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Data Neo4j 4 is the newest version, a complete rewrite from scratch focussing on Neo4j server, see also:

http://neo4j.com/developer/spring-data-neo4j/

It builds on top of a pure Java OGM which uses the server transport and will use the binary protocol in the future.

There are migration notes for people coming from SDN 3

If you are starting a new project go with SDN4

Comment: SDN4 doesn't support embedded mode yet. Would that be a reason to stick with SDN3 for now?

Comment: @MichaelHunger In addition to not supporting embedded mode, SDN4 doesn't support `@Query`-annotated fields on entity classes, which IMO was a huge readability win in SDN3 - is this on the roadmap?. Also, `@QueryResult` can't map to entities - I know that's on the roadmap for 4.1.0, but can you offer any insight into when we might see that released?

Comment: mapped query results are planned / worked on; I don't think that annotated fields were such a good idea. and embedded support is also planned for 4.1 which is due I think in Feb

Comment: @MichaelHunger interesting, why do you think annotated fields weren't such a good idea?